# Export Google Spreadsheet and related scripts

Tags: google-apps-script

I have a Google SpreadSheet with some custom scripts to do stuffs.

Is there a way to export the "bundle" (sheets+scripts), so that if I import the file (on another folder/Drive) I'll get a clone (sheets+scripts) of the original? Looks like it is possible to only export the SpreadSheet.

EDIT:

To better explain the scenario, I'd like to export spreadsheet+script to use a local version control system to better "log" my development. The Google script version control is not enough detailed for my purpose. If one can download/upload linked spreadsheet/script (also forma/script) it will be quite handy.

Answer (score 0):

You can't really export/import your "bundle" like export it as file and import it again.

But when you make a copy of a spreadsheet, you also copy the script related to this sheet. So you can make a workaround by using the method to copy a file([copy()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/spreadsheet#copy(String))), and change the owner of it ([setOwner()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/drive/file#setOwner(String))). You'll keep the sheet with the script related and it will be transfered.

Answer (score 0):

If the script is bound to the spreadsheet then any copies of the sheet will also have their own copies of the script. If you need to copy the sheet to a different GDrive account just share the sheet with that account (granting edit access) and the user of that account can make their own copy of the sheet.